# Scala - multiple function, returns multiple function

Tags: scala, generics

I started to learn the basics of scala and and I have problem with understanding simple function. I have three tasks to do. First of them was easy for me and i know how it works. But next two I don't understand what I have to write to return.

```
def compose[A,B,C](f: A => B)(g: B => C): A => C = {
            a: A => g(f(a))
        }


def prod[A,B,C,D](f: A => C, g: B => D): (A, B) => (C, D) {
???????????
}


def lift[A,T](op: (T,T) => T)(f: A => T, g: A => T): A => T {
??????????
}
```

Comment: Since the best is to try to help you figure out the solution rather than just giving the code I would invite you to the [**Scala Discord** server](https://discord.gg/4ubXNJVV) so we can provide you more interactive help :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the types, you should be able to implement the method quite easily by looking at the them.

Start with `prod`, start by writing the input parameters and expected output:

```scala
def prod[A,B,C,D](f: A => C, g: B => D): (A, B) => (C, D) = {
  (a: A, b: B) => {
    val c: C = ???
    val d: D = ???
    (c, d) 
  }
}
```

Then, how can you build `c` and `d` given what you have (that is `f` and `g`)?

I let you answer this question by yourself.

---

The same can be applied for `lift`:

```scala
def lift[A,T](op: (T,T) => T)(f: A => T, g: A => T): A => T {
  (a: A) => {
    val t: T = ???
  }
}
```

This one might be a bit trickier if you have no idea what `lift` is supposed to do though.
Hint: you probably have to use `f` and `g`, otherwise they wouldn't exist. Then from the values you get, how to get the desired output type?